# How to select a nested element

Tags: jquery

In this HTML:

```
<div class="seal">
    <div class="how with"> </div>
    <div class="how"> </div>
    <div class="with"> </div>
</div>
```

How can I select this nested element?:

```
<div class="how with"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="seal">

    <div class="how with"> </div>
    <div class="how"> </div>
    <div class="with"> </div>
</div>
```

selector .seal:

```
var seal = jQuery(".seal");
```

selector .how

```
jQuery(".how", seal);
```

selector .with

```
jQuery(".with", seal);
```

selector .how and .with

```
jQuery(".how.with", seal);
```

or

```
jQuery(".seal .how.with");
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors:

```
$('.seal .how.with')
```